# Creating a method for action Real problem

Tags: c++, methods, subclass

The goal is to Create a constructor for both subclasses of the  Character class to initialize all public and private properties in the Character class and subclasses. What am I doing wrong?

I already know to do that I started to put two separate constructors into each class but am still confused a little.  The code is provided below:

```
// RequimOcculation.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>





class GameStructure { //Creating Base Class; derivative of Character class.

private: //Private property; for what to not be shown
    
    int  WarpWeapon[4] = {25, 16, 50, 100};// interger for WarpWeapon is assign an array of 4 elements
    int gun [3] = {50, 10, 5}; // interger for Gun is assign an array of 3 elements
    




};

class Characters:public GameStructure { //class derived class is created

    public: // public property
        std::string Name; // string name
        
        void trackDamage(int d) {// creating setter
            health = d; 
            if (d==!100)
            {
                std::cout << "Bloop; Character has expired!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Battle!\n";
            }
       }
        
        int showDamage() { //created getter
            return health;
        }
        class Speaking : public Characters {
        
        public:
            void Talk() {
                std::cout << "Take that!";
            }
        };


private: //private property
    int health; //interger for health is assign with 100
       


};

class Humans : public  Characters { //class humans is created to derive from characters

    std::string person = "Firing"; // creation of string person with the assignment of Firiing

public: //public property
    void action() { //void function action
         std::cout << person << "Pow Pow (Sound effect)!!!" << std::endl; // text to be seen with the person function
    }

   // Trigger1::Trigger1(int gun) { //attempt to create a constructor using as the object interger gun given from game structure classs 


    //}
  

};

class Aliens : public Characters { //class derive from the charaters class called Aliens
    std::string green = "Blasting";
public:
    void action() {
         std::cout << green <<"Bling Bling(Sound effect)!!!" << std::endl;

    }
    //trigger::trigger(int WarpWeapon) {

   //}
 
};



int main()
{
    std::cout << "In the far far future,humanity now lives in glass dome cities\n";
    std::cout << "All of sudden... ";
    std::cout << "Warp(sound effect)...";
    std::cout << "Aliens evade dome city sector A01 so it is time to battle." << std::endl;
    
    Characters myCharacter1;
    myCharacter1.Talk();



    Characters showHe;
    showHe.trackDamage(0);
    std::cout << showHe.showDamage();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot have a statement like `std::cout << ...` directly in a class. It should be placed in a method of the class.

Comment: Just have it there for its intended use

Comment: Are you trying to use inheritage? It's totally unclear what you're trying to achieve. The whole thing doesn't make any sense...And BTW there are no C++ "scripts".

Comment: Can you explain in plain english what you are trying to accomplish? Because the C++ code does not make any sense.

Comment: Maybe you just need to google _simple inheritance example in c++_.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make the question any clearer. It's still totally unclear what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: What I need is the code to have a health bar, some pointers thrown for deduction for the player when action, and that is it really.